# time() and context switching

Tags: c

I am more or less wondering how `time()` is implemented in the C standard library and what would happen in the situation described below. Although this time is most-likely negligible, consider a situation where you have a hard-limit on time and no control over the CPU scheduler (assume that it is a "good" scheduler for a general-purpose CPU).

Now, if I use `time()` to calculate my execution time of a particular section of code and use this time subtracted from some maximum bound to determine some other time-dependent variable, how would this variable be skewed based on context-switches? I know we could use `nice` and other tools (i.e. custom scheduler, etc.) to be certain we get full CPU usage when we need it, however, I am wondering how this works in general for similar situations as this and what side-effects exist due to the system's choices.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Context switches take non-zero time, so if they occur during your measurement period, then the measurement will be larger than otherwise.  I'm sure you're aware of that, so what is it you're asking?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity; I am asking how large this effect is and how it can be modified programmatically (if possible). I believe Jerry's response below answers it thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time` is supposed to measure wall-time. I.e., it gives the current time, regardless of how much or little your process has run.

If you want to measure cpu time, you should use `clock` instead (though some vendors such as MS implement it wrong, so it does wall time also).

Of course, there are also other tools to retrieve CPU usage, such as [`times`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times) on Unix-like systems or [`GetProcessTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223.aspx) on Windows. Most people find these more useful despite the reduced portability.